# Error in specifying documentID while creating document in Appwrite Collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, appwrite

I am trying to create a document in appwrite
`

```
const read = await this.databases.createDocument(config.databaseID, config.userReadCollectionID, JSON.stringify(data),ID.unique());
```

But i am getting this error.
`AppwriteException: Invalid` documentId`param: Parameter must contain at most 36 chars. Valid chars are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, period, hyphen, and underscore. Can't start with a special char`

I tried slicing the uniqueId to below 36 but it still doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to [`createDocument()`](https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-web/blob/ca8cb1d9f2c0393ec99c7d5cb50f3be543987918/src/services/databases.ts#L63) is the documentId:

```js
async createDocument<Document extends Models.Document>(databaseId: string, collectionId: string, documentId: string, data: Omit<Document, keyof Models.Document>, permissions?: string[]): Promise<Document>
```

So, it looks like you're passing `JSON.stringify(data)` for the documentId which is probably invalid. It should probably be:

```
const read = await this.databases.createDocument(config.databaseID, config.userReadCollectionID, ID.unique(), data);
```

assuming `data` is a JSON object.